# C Looping through pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to do some simple algorithms with C but I get stuck pretty quickly by an issue with pointers to arrays.
I have looked at both:

[Loop through an array with pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213551/loop-through-an-array-with-pointers)

[How to loop through a string created by pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993591/how-to-loop-through-a-string-created-by-pointer)

[C for loop through array with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434177/c-for-loop-through-array-with-pointers)

and I don't think either answers my question.
Say I want to make a library function that takesan array of indeterminate length as a parameter:

```
void library_func(int* arr){
    //I want to loop through array. 
    while(some_condition){
       do_stuff(*arr);
       arr++;//increment pointer.
    }
}
```

I don't know what I can use for an indeterminate length array for "some_condition". From one of the above Answers, it seems if I used a char array I could dereference the pointer and compare to '\0'. But what about any other type,  including structs?

Comment: You pass in the length, hence making it no longer of indeterminate length.

Comment: Must I pass the length? Is there no comparison to find if I have strayed beyond the array's bounds?

Comment: You either need to pass in the length, or define a sentinel value (which is what '\0' is the case of a string).

Comment: You can use any value you want to signal the end of an array. The convention is to use `NULL` for arrays of pointers, but no special value is available for primitive types other than `char`. `0` may do well for integers, provided it is not significant in your case.

Comment: Since it is a library function,enforcing rules that the caller's array end in some way may not be always possible isn't? I think the best is to ask the caller to pass the length which it should be aware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only option is:

```
void library_func(int* arr,size_t len){
    //I want to loop through array. 
    while(len){
       do_stuff(*arr);
       arr++;//increment pointer.
       len--;
    }
}
```

the option you are referring that is used for string (`'\0'`) is to use some special int to mark the end of the array, but I strongly suggest to avoid it. The magic value '\0' is easily accepted with strings, all programmers know about that,and it is the `ascii` `'nul'` value, that in the string domain is accepted as a special value. For integer there is no such a concept.

Of course you can shorten the code as suggested in the comemnts below.

Comment: Is this the standard C way of doing such a thing?

Comment: @Caveman Usually a `size_t` is used (or at least an unsigned value) to ensure some fiend didn't pass something negative to this and thus spin you down the rabbit hole long-past your array limits (think about what this does with `-1` as `len` on inception).

Comment: @WhozCraig Right, that's why the above approach seems a bit fishy to me. There is plenty of room for all kind of errors. (But I suppose at lower levels you can't expect a handed-to-you-for-free array.length like higher level languages)

Comment: @Caveman Yeah, but I +1 it regardless. the idea is correct. this is the usual the modus-operandi in C unless your data specific support some known terminator such as strings. (and even then, it doesn't reflect the length of the *array*; rather it reflects the length of the sequence you *care about*; the array could still be larger).

Comment: @FelicePollano figured you would do so. I up-ticked regardless. Right idea. Oh, and the short version: `while (len--) do_stuff(*arr++);` assuming you don't need `len` after this is finished.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank, I will leave the long one in the reply that is probably simpler to get at a first glance

Answer (score 0):

The "\0" null terminator is just to indicate the end of an char string

to do looping through other type of array you must provide the length.

```
void library_func(int* arr,int length){
//I want to loop through array. 
while(length){ // checking remaining arrays
   do_stuff(*arr);
   arr++;//increment pointer.
   length --;
   }
```

The length variable servers as a check for the number of remaining elements. when it reaches zero it will not enter the loop. without the length variable the loop keep on increment even beyond the length of the array - depends on the compiler some might give an error while others might give a warning-. this means that the loop might never exist until the application crashes